# Rails 3 respond_with returning associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a simple Rails 3.2 controller which is consumed as an API with JSON:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ReportsController < Api::V1::ApplicationController
      def index
        respond_with Report.where(name: params[:name])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

(there is no code is the parent controllers)

When I consume this method, I'm getting all reports back, as expected, but I'm also getting all the associations.  I don't see why this is and want to stop it.

Why am I getting the associations?

Comment: How are you generating your JSON?

Comment: maybe you have serializers gem in your app, I know that they are used to get a json response with associations.

Comment: @ZachKemp JSON is just being created via Rails with `responds_with :json`

Answer (score 0):

As @rmagnum2002 eluded to, I found `active_model_serializers` bundled into the app, and someone had created a serializer for that model without me noticing it.